# Get refreanceData on error in OnSubmit in spring MVC 2.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring MVC and using `Spring MVC 2.5 and SimpleFormController` every thing is working fine the only issue is that i have to validate some values in OnSubmit so i do that like

```
    if (value == null) {
        request.setAttribute("schedulemeeting", meeting);
        return new ModelAndView("schedulemeeting", "error",
                responseParser.getErrorMessage());

    }
```

SO this load the form and displays the error but i'm not getting the `referenceData` which is set. So my form's drop-down list become empty on error.

What need to be done to make it work

Answer (score 1):

For Spring MVC 2.5, put your logic in a [`Validator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) and [inject it in your `SimpleFormController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html#setValidator%28org.springframework.validation.Validator%29).

However, for new development you should not be extending any of Spring's form controllers since [they are deprecated in Spring 3.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html).